# Piwik MySQL DB: calculate length of user actions

Tags: mysql, session, web-analytics, matomo, logfile

I'm trying to calculate the length of an user action on a website that was tracked by Piwik. The session data is stored in the MySQL table 'log_visit_action'.

In the column 'time_spent_action' I want to calculate the time the user spent till taking the next action or till leaving the website (no further action assigned to the 'idvisit').

In Excel I would know how to solve the problem. Per se it's not difficult. But since I'm new to MySQL I have no idea how to implement it on this MySQL table with 50 million entries. Perhaps you can provide some code examples?

This is a screenshot of the table structure I exported to Excel.
Here you can find some example data on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62f235/3).

Many thanks in advance,
Lars

[image: Table Structure]

Comment: Place an table on http://www.sqlfiddle.com with some example data

Comment: Here is some example data:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62f235/3

Comment: Hello Raymond, do you think you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came over the same problem, recently. Therefore, here's a solution, working with temporary tables. Actually, I offer two solutions.

**Solution (A)** identifies the subsequent log_action_link using a subquery (very time-consuming)

```
# Very time-consuming
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
    (INDEX idlink_follow (idlink_follow))
    SELECT idlink_va, time_spent_ref_action AS time_spent_action, idvisit, (
        SELECT idlink_va FROM piwik_log_link_visit_action b
        WHERE (a.idvisit = b.idvisit) AND (b.idlink_va < a.idlink_va)
        ORDER BY idlink_va
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS idlink_follow
    FROM piwik_log_link_visit_action a
    ORDER BY idvisit DESC, idlink_va DESC;
```

Solution (B) depends on a clean and complete `piwik_log_link_visit_action` table. This is usually the case, but you can never be perfectly sure.

```
# Create table containing the time per action
# (requires a clean and complete piwik_log_link_visit_action)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpA
SELECT idlink_va, time_spent_ref_action, idvisit
    FROM piwik_log_link_visit_action
    ORDER BY idvisit, idlink_va;
SELECT * FROM tmpA;

SET @lagID = NULL;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
    (INDEX idlink_follow (idlink_follow))
    SELECT @lagID AS idlink_follow, time_spent_ref_action AS time_spent_action, @lagID:=idlink_va AS idlink_va
    FROM tmpA
    ORDER BY idvisit, idlink_va;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmpA;
```

Based on the temporary table, the page times can be accessed:

```
SELECT l.idvisit, t.time_spent_action, l.*
FROM piwik_log_link_visit_action l
LEFT JOIN tmp t ON (t.idlink_follow = l.idlink_va)
ORDER BY l.idvisit, l.server_time
```

Mind to delete the temporary table.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This really did it for me. Great job! I chose Solution A. For a table with 12 million entries the first step took about 3,5 hours.